# Swagger not showing multiple versions of APIs

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

In Spring Boot app,I have created a directory "V1_2" and added one controller in directory which is another version of API which is present in V1_1.The versioning is based on "produces" attribute i.e.for 1.1 produces="application/v1.1json" and for 1.2 "produces=application/v1.2json".But when I load the swagger UI,I am expecting it to show both APIs but it is showing only V1_2.

Comment: Can you post your code and the screenshots of Swagger UI?